# How do I keep salt from eroding a concrete driveway?

Tags: winter, garage

I've noticed over the past few years that my concrete driveway is slowing eroding away.  I've read the road/rock salt can erode concrete, so I'm attributing the cause to salt.

[image]

Source of salt: I don't add salt much, but the city sprays it over the driveway regularly and there is often salty runoff from the car.  In short, I can't think of a way to avoid the salt.

Any ideas how to minimize this effect without buying expensive sealants/treatments?

Comment: You should ask your question on [Home Improvement SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com). This is a common home maintenance problem and isn't likely solvable by a "life hack."

Answer (score 2):

If the effect is indeed salt, then your best option is to try to avoid the salt staying there for any prolonged time. This is hard to achieve, but you could maybe wash out your driveway after a period where you know there has been used a lot of salt on the roads.

Similarily you could/should wash the bottom of your car to remove salt from it. This also helps the car from rusting, as the salt accelerates the rust process.

But other than this, I do believe you need to look at other forms of treatment of your driveway. You could possibly get some dedicated painting, which could help you a little...

Comment: Usually salt is put out to prevent a layer of ice from forming. Washing your driveway will only increase the chance of a thin layer of black ice forming. I would not try this if the temperature outside is still below freezing.

Comment: @TotZam, that kind of goes without saying. My point is that when the temperature raises again, one should wash away the salt as soon as possible.